# WP8 Image processing with pixel shader

Tags: 2d, windows-phone-8, pixel-shader

Is there a way to perform this in XAML app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a complicated answer and it depends on which platform your WP8 app is written for and what specifically you're trying to accomplish.

1. No, you can't use XAML with HLSL pixel shaders on WP8 like you could on Silverlight. That's not supported for WP7/WP8.
2. Yes, you can use HLSL pixel shaders on D3D WP8 apps. They do have to be compiled at prior to marketplace submission and not at run-time. See full details on this see MSDN @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714072(v=vs.105).aspx
3. Also, you can write your own custom C++ image processing code as a Windows Phone Runtime component that gets called from C#. You can also optimize that code to work really fast with WP8 by working with the SIMD\Neon instruction set. We're actively working on an end-to-end Wp8 sample of that in Nokia that demos [image processing for camera input](http://projects.developer.nokia.com/NativeFilterDemo). In the meanwhile there's a working demo that shows how to invoke [SIMD\NEON optimized C++ code](http://projects.developer.nokia.com/NativeFilterDemo/browser/NativeComponent/NativeComponent.cpp) from [C#](http://projects.developer.nokia.com/NativeFilterDemo/browser/NativeFilterDemo/CameraStreamSource.cs).